# Web Audio Api - Download edited MP3

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I'm currently editing my mp3 file with multiple effects like so

```
var mainVerse = document.getElementById('audio1');

var s = source;
source.disconnect(audioCtx.destination);

for (var i in filters1) {
 s.connect(filters1[i]);
 s = filters1[i];
}

s.connect(audioCtx.destination);
```

The mp3 plays accordingly on the web with the filters on it. Is it possible to create and download a new mp3 file with these new effects, using web audio api or any writing to mp3 container javascript library ? If not whats the best to solve this on the web ?

UPDATE - Using OfflineAudioContext

Using the sample code from `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext/oncomplete`

I've tried using the offline node like so;

```
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
var offlineCtx = new OfflineAudioContext(2,44100*40,44100);

osource = offlineCtx.createBufferSource();

function getData() {
      request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open('GET', 'Song1.mp3', true);
      request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
      request.onload = function() {
        var audioData = request.response;
        audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {
          myBuffer = buffer;
          osource.buffer = myBuffer;
          osource.connect(offlineCtx.destination);
          osource.start();
          //source.loop = true;
          offlineCtx.startRendering().then(function(renderedBuffer) {
            console.log('Rendering completed successfully');
            var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)(); 
            var song = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
            song.buffer = renderedBuffer;
            song.connect(audioCtx.destination);
            song.start();
            rec = new Recorder(song, {
                workerPath: 'Recorderjs/recorderWorker.js'
            });   

            rec.exportWAV(function(e){
                rec.clear();
                Recorder.forceDownload(e, "filename.wav");
            });
          }).catch(function(err) {
              console.log('Rendering failed: ' + err);
              // Note: The promise should reject when startRendering is called a second time on an OfflineAudioContext
          });
        });
      }
      request.send();
    }
    // Run getData to start the process off
getData();
```

Still getting the recorder to download an empty file, I'm using the song source as the source for the recorder. The song plays and everything with his code but recorder doesn't download it

Comment: You're looking for recorder.js
https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

Comment: @RaphaelSerota Hello I was just checking out the library, and I wasn't sure how to get the `forceDownload` working with an already existing source (rather than recording with the mic i.e `rec.record() , rec.stop()` ). I'm currently doing the following  `rec = new Recorder(s, {
      workerPath: 'Recorderjs/recorderWorker.js'
    });
    
    
    rec.exportWAV(function(e){
     Recorder.forceDownload(e, "filename.wav");
    });`... but the filename.wav file is an empty wav file ... any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Use https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs to record a .wav file. Then use https://github.com/akrennmair/libmp3lame-js to encode it to .mp3.

There's a nifty guide here, if you need a hand: http://audior.ec/blog/recording-mp3-using-only-html5-and-javascript-recordmp3-js/

***UPDATE***

Try moving

```
rec = new Recorder(song, {
    workerPath: 'Recorderjs/recorderWorker.js'
});
```

so that it is located above the call to start rendering, and connect it to osource instead, like so:

```
rec = new Recorder(osource, {
      workerPath: 'Recorderjs/recorderWorker.js'
}); 
osource.connect(offlineCtx.destination);
osource.start();
offlineCtx.startRendering().then(function(renderedBuffer) {
     .....
```

Comment: Hello I was just checking out the recorderJS library, and I wasn't sure how to get the `forceDownload` working with an already existing source (rather than recording with the mic i.e `rec.record() , rec.stop()` ). I'm currently doing the following `rec = new Recorder(s, { workerPath: 'Recorderjs/recorderWorker.js' }); rec.exportWAV(function(e){ Recorder.forceDownload(e, "filename.wav"); }); `... but the filename.wav file is an empty wav file ... any suggestions ?

Comment: That's because (if the above is all you do) the standrad context in Web Audio renders in real time, so if you do it like that without first playing the audio, you'll have nothing. You'll have to call .record() on the recorder and then play your processed audio for it to record anything, and then stop it and do a force download. Alternatively, have a look at the offline context which doesn't render in real time (probably what you want) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OfflineAudioContext @Thatdude1

Comment: Hey I've updated the question where I tried using the offline context but its still not downloading the file.. any suggestions ? Thanks